# Forwarding nameserver with cloudflare

Tags: dns, hosting, cloudflare, nameservers

I'm trying to use a host but my registrar won't approve to change nameserver of that host, however, my domain is now pointing to Cloudflare's nameserver. So, is there any way to change nameserver from Cloudflare?

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to change nameserver from Cloudflare?

Authoritative nameservers can only be changed at the domain registrar.

You can't change the nameserver from within Cloudflare, unless Cloudflare itself is your domain registrar.